# How to use FormulateInput of type 'select' with v-for in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I have a form in which two inputs have the type of 'select that one of them depends on the another, the first input called Area which gets its options dynamically from the server and the other one which is called City gets its options based on the Area input.

That was the code in HTML:

```html
<select v-model="areaSelected">                                              
  <option v-for="area in areas" :key="area.id" :value="area.id">
    {{area.ar_name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

I want to convert it into Vue.JS code using InputFormulate.

This is what I did, but didn't work:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<FormulateInput

  v-model="areaSelected"

  v-for="area in areas"

  :key="area.id"

  :value="area.id"

  :options="area.ar_name"

  type="select"

  placeholder="المنطقة"

  label="اختر المنطقة"

/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use `v-for` in `FormulateInput`, just put your `areas` in `:options` props.

Based on its [documentation](https://vueformulate.com/guide/inputs/types/select/#select-2) you can do like so:

```html
<FormulateInput
  v-model="areaSelected"
  :options="areas"
  type="select"
  placeholder="المنطقة"
  label="اختر المنطقة"
/>
```

`areas` could be an array of object or could be an objects.

```
:options="{first: 'First', second: 'Second', third: 'Third', fourth: 'Fourth'}"
```

```
:options="[
    { value: 'first', label: 'First name' },
    { value: 'last', label: 'Last name' },
    { value: 'initial', label: 'Middle Initial', id: 'name-initial' }
  ]"
```

**UPDATE**

I assume that your `areas` or the data from your database is an array of objects with structure like so:

```
let areas = [{
  id: 1,
  ar_name: 'a name 1'
},{
  id: 2,
  ar_name: 'a name 2'
}]
```

Whereas based in FormulateInput documentation is that they need structure like this `[{ value: 'first', label: 'First name' }]`. So you just need to convert your objects **key** name like what FormulateInput is required.

Try to do this in VueJS

```js
computed: {
    modifiedAreas () {
      let newAreas = this.areas.map(({ id, ar_name }) => ({ value: id, label: ar_name }));
      return newAreas
    }
 }
```

And change you `options` with this.

```html
<FormulateInput
  v-model="areaSelected"
  :options="modifiedAreas"
  type="select"
  placeholder="المنطقة"
  label="اختر المنطقة"
/>
```

Comment: The options are not hard-coded, it is actually coming from a database and that's why I need to use v-for.

Comment: that's just an example, you can put your data from database to `:options`

Comment: How can I loop through these data?

Comment: @kusiaga There must be some way to specify first default null/blank value labeled `"Select any one..."` in the `:options` array / object, how can that be done ? As far as I've tried this isn't working `{value: '', label: "Select any one..."}`, disappointing..